# ember.js loop fails on version 2.4.1

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have the following code from tutorialpoint on ember 1.10. It works fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Emberjs displaying list of items</title>
      <!-- CDN's-->
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/3.0.1/handlebars.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember.js/1.10.0/ember.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.10.0-beta.3/ember-template-compiler.js"></script>
      <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/release/ember.debug.js"></script>
      <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/beta/ember-data.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <script type="text/x-handlebars">
         <ul>
           <!-- Getting each value of the myArray -->
            {{#each value in App.myArray}}
               <!-- diplaying the values -->
               <li>{{value}}</li>
            {{/each}}
         </ul>
      </script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
         var App = Ember.Application.create()
         //creating the array
         App.myArray = ['Mona','Manu','Mack']
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

However if I changed the version from

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember.js/1.10.0/ember.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember.js/2.4.1/ember.min.js"></script>
```

then the code stopped working with no error. My first question is how can I make it work under 2.4?

My second question is, even under version 1.1, if I use id="{{value}}" it won't work. How can I assign {{}} to DOM element id, like this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Emberjs displaying list of items</title>
      <!-- CDN's-->
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember.js/1.10.0/ember.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.10.0-beta.3/ember-template-compiler.js"></script>
      <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/release/ember.debug.js"></script>
      <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/beta/ember-data.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <script type="text/x-handlebars">
         <ul>
           <!-- Getting each value of the myArray -->
            {{#each value in App.myArray}}
               <!-- diplaying the values -->
               <li id="{{value}}">{{value}}</li>
            {{/each}}
         </ul>
      </script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
         var App = Ember.Application.create()
         //creating the array
         App.myArray = ['Mona','Manu','Mack']
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

UPDATE:
I changed to new syntax as below but it still won't work.

```
   <body>
      <script type="text/x-handlebars">         
        <ul>
          {{#each App.people as |person|}}
            <li>Hello, {{person}}!</li>
          {{/each}}
        </ul> 
      </script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
         var App = Ember.Application.create()
         //creating the array
         App.people = ['Mona','Manu','Mack']
      </script>
   </body>
```

Comment: I'm not sure using globals like that will work on 2.x. That each syntax is also not supported, it should be `{{#each someArray as |value|}}`. I suggest you follow more recent resources, like the official guides.

Comment: hi, locks, thanks for the reply. The new syntax does't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ember 2.x won't do global lookup from within templates, so code like `SomeConst.someProperty` is looking for a *local* property named `SomeConst`, not a global variable.

It will only do local lookup for its context (either a controller instance if the template was rendered by the router or, more commonly, a component's instance if the template was rendered by a component.

Here is a working example of what you're trying: http://jsbin.com/racacitiko/1/edit?html

Comment: Hi, Trek, Thank you so much. You saved my day:)